# Self calls and object in the middle of lifeline

Tags: pgf-umlsd

I am drawing an attached sequence diagram but some of the components couldn't figure out (highlighted in red boxes(red boxes are not required)). Please advice

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newthread{FD}{FirstObject}{}
        \newinst[2]{FH}{SecondObject}{}
        \newinst[2]{VM}{ThirdObject0}{}
        \newinst[2]{FC}{FourthObject0}{}                
        \begin{call}{FD}{processEvent()}{FH}{}  
            \begin{call}{FH}{processEvent()}{VM}{processEvent()}
                \begin{call}{VM}{processEvent()}{FC}{processEvent()}        
                \end{call}      
                \begin{call}{VM}{processEvent()}{VM}{}              
                \end{call}              
            \end{call}                                  
        \end{call}          
    \end{sequencediagram}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please specify which components you are especially interested in?

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks for coming back. Components highlighted in red boxes in updated figure.

Comment: Okay, this is intended behavior as far as I can tell. `pgf-umlsd` does only provide self calls with two arrows. Maybe the package `tikz-uml` (manual see [here](https://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/var/files/doc/tikzumlmanual.pdf)) would be better suited.